# UnityでBundle Identifierを変更後にiOSでローカル通知が動かなくなりました

Tags: c#, unity3d

お分かりになる方いらっしゃいましたら、お教えください。

UnityでiOSアプリを制作しております。

ローカル通知を実装し正常に動いていたのですが、Bundle Identifierを変更してから、
ローカル通知が動かなくなってしまいました。

iPhoneの設定 > 通知と辿りましてもアプリ自体が認識されません。

ホーム画面にはアプリアイコンが表示され、通常通り動作致します。しかし、ローカル通知がだけが全く反応しない状態となります。

元のBundle Identifierに戻してからビルドしますと正常にローカルプッシュが作動します。

Bundle Identifierを途中で変更するとこのような事が起きるのでしょうか？
検索したのですが、情報を見つける事が出来ずにおります。

Unity4.6.8f1
Xcode6.4
実機はiPhone6、iPhone5でiOS8.3を使ってテストしております。

古いBundle Identifierでビルドすると正常に動作。
新しくBundle Identifierを設定してビルドするとローカル通知は作動せず、アプリ自体は正常に動作する状態です。

よろしくお願い致します。